# Ocaml Sort Program

Tags: sorting, ocaml

I wrote these lines of code so as to sort the input of 5 numbers.

But when i compile and run it, then there is an error like - "int_of_string"

I do not know why this is not running. I am new to Ocaml.

```
   let sort2 (a, b) = if a<b 
               then (a, b)
               else (b, a)

let sort3 (a, b, c) = 
    let (a, b) = sort2(a, b) in
    let (b, c) = sort2(b, c) in
    let (a, b) = sort2(a, b) in
    (a, b, c)


let sort5 (a, b, c, d, e) = 



let (a, b, c) = sort3 (a, b, c) in
let (c, d, e) = sort3(c, d, e) in
let (a, b, c) = sort3 (a, b, c) in
(a, b, c, d, e)

let _ =
let a = read_int () in 
let b = read_int () in 
let c = read_int () in 
let d = read_int () in 
let e = read_int () in 
let (a, b, c, d, e) = sort5 (a, b, c, d, e) in 
print_int a; print_newline ();
print_int b; print_newline ();
print_int c; print_newline ();
print_int d; print_newline ();
print_int e; print_newline ()
```

Comment: If this is OCaml, why did you pick the tags 'java' and 'java.util.scanner'?

Comment: When I run this code in the OCaml REPL (known as "toplevel") I don't see your reported problem. I enter 5 numbers and it sorts them.

Answer (score 2):

```
Exception: Failure "int_of_string".
```

The exception happens when you type a line of input that cannot be parsed as an integer, such as an empty line. This must be what happened during your tests.

#### Error handling

If you want a little bit of robustness, you have to take into account that the input can be malformed. You can catch the runtime error to handle unexpected inputs:

```
# let maybe_read_int () = try Some (read_int ()) with Failure _ -> None;;
val maybe_read_int : unit -> int option = <fun>
```

The value returned from the above function is an `int option`.

Failure

```
# maybe_read_int ();;
foo
- : int option = None
```

Success

```
# maybe_read_int ();;
42
- : int option = Some 42
```

#### Reading multiple integers

You can't just use the above function like in your example because some of your variables would be bound to `None` (in that case, this is no better that letting the exception bubble up). Instead, you  may want to read as many lines as necessary until you get 5 integers:

```
let rec read_n_ints n =
  if (n > 0) then
    match (maybe_read_int ()) with
    | None -> read_n_ints n
    | Some v -> v :: (read_n_ints (n - 1))
  else [];;

# read_n_ints 3;;
0
foo
bar
1
2
- : int list = [0; 1; 2]
```

Now that you have a list of integers, you can bind them to variables using pattern matching. Note that we have to be exhaustive and consider cases that should not happen:

```
#   match (read_n_ints 5) with
  | [ a; b; c; d; e] -> (a + b + c + d + e)
  | _ -> raise (Failure "Failed to read 5 integers");;    
3   
foo
2 
10
30
ii
r
90
3
- : int = 136
```